# (Game) Display 200 + unlockable items in UITableView or manually in ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

Iv been working on a game for 4 months not and development is going smoothly since im new to iOS apps. Basically its a game where the user can collect points and unlock weapons to use to kill and get more points.

The "Store" View Controller is where I want to display all of the unlockable guns.

There are :

1. 200 + guns ( 3-4 guns per row/cell)
2. 25 different categories (Sections? or Seperate UITableViews?)

Check the image below as its similar to what im looking to build..except with guns.

[image: Example]

As you can see above some of them are unlocked and some are locked. I want the same concept but with guns.

Im trying to figure out the best way to create this with UITableView.

Since there are 25 categories (ex: Shotgun category with 30 + different skins to unlock. 4 skins each row.) Should I make each categories a different UITableView or just use Sections?

Hopefully i explained it decently, if not let me know ill give more detail!

Thank you!

Comment: You should use a `UICollectionView`